# JUnit 4.9 greaterThan assert

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea, assert, junit4

I am using JUnit4.9.zip. I downloaded it from https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/downloads. I am also using IntelliJ 10.5 as my text editor. I am having a problem getting the assertThat method to work with the greaterThan function. Basically I just want to make sure that the int result that I am getting from a method is not negative.

Here is the problem: IntelliJ can't seem to locate the greaterThan function that is used by JUnit. What am I missing/doing wrong? What do I need to get this to work.

Comment: Are you talking about a compile-time error because the method can't be found, or a lack of intellisense-like functionality in your IDE?

Comment: I am referring to the compile-time error.

Comment: Ok. Then it would help to edit your question and post the text of the error and any other info your IDE throws up; and the full classpath you're using as suggested by @CrazyCoder. Otherwise, we're just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Check what JUnit libraries you have in the [module dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html), most likely there is also an old version that appears first in the classpath.